# How to change border of this image

Tags: ios, image, border, frame

I am making a game using this function:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(object.frame, object2.frame)) {
   [self GameOver];
}
```

Both objects are square however the image of object #2 is not. Therefore when the borders collide (but not the actual pictures) the game ends. Is there a way I can have the border "fit" to the image, so that the game only ends when the actual pictures collide.

Thanks :)

**my image is a shark and therefore a rectangle cannot be used

Comment: It would be a better approach to try using SpriteKit (or corona,cocos2d etc) as the UIKit doesn't have the tools for more sophisticated collision detection

Answer (score 0):

A view's frame is always a CGRect, which is a rectangle. You can use UIKit Dynamics for collision detection with views, but that only support rectangles too.

As @jammycoder mentioned, try out SpriteKit or other game engines, if you need to detect custom shape bounds.

Comment: Yeah thanks I really want to use sprite kit. Do you know of a good tutorial addressing the issue? I have looked but not been successful. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure thing! The best source of iOS tutorials is Ray Wenderlich's site, where you can also download source codes, like in this very basic example:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners
After that, you can read this about the physics features:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/63229/make-game-like-mega-jump-spritekit-part-12
It may seems a little complicated first, but SpriteKit is a very light game engine, so if you learn the basics, you already know a big part of it.